# How to save Pie chart into ppt slides using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, powerpoint

I want to save my R pie plot to pptx so I managed to reach the last step of code.

```
df <- data.frame(Type = c('x','y'),Count = c(177,41))
ggplt <- ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = Count, fill = Type)) +
         geom_col(width = 1) +
         scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "yellow")) +
         coord_polar("y") + 
         geom_text(aes(label = paste0("Count=",Count)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
         labs(title = "Employees Count")

myppt <- read_pptx()
myppt <-  add_slide(myppt,layout="Two Content",master = "Office Theme")
myppt <- ph_with(myppt,type = "body",value = ggplt,location = ph_location_left())
```

while running the last statement of `ph_with()` I am getting error saying:

```
Error in match.arg(type) : 
  'arg' should be one of “windows”, “cairo”, “cairo-png”
```

I would appreciate if someone could tell where I am messing up the things !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you used `type="body"` in `ph_with` which however has no `type` argument. Therefore the `type` argument is passed on via `...` to the `png()` function which gives rise to the mysterious error.

This said, you could achieve your desired result by removing `type="body"`:

```r
library(officer)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Type = c('x','y'),Count = c(177,41))
ggplt <- ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = Count, fill = Type)) +
  geom_col(width = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "yellow")) +
  coord_polar("y") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0("Count=",Count)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  labs(title = "Employees Count")

myppt <- read_pptx()
myppt <-  add_slide(myppt,layout="Two Content",master = "Office Theme")
myppt <- ph_with(myppt, value = ggplt, location = ph_location_left()) 

print(myppt, "foo.pptx")
```

[image]

Comment: Oh!! i see.. Thank you @stefan.

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at `rmarkdown`. With it you can knit (convert) you r file or report into a pptx file. To access this you klick new file in rstudio and than press new markdown file.